# How to automatically update resources in a Cordova application?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have a cordova hybrid application and mobile web application. I came across a problem while application upgrade. Mobile web application works perfectly as all the static files which are modified are fetched from web server. But my hybrid application is not upgraded. I can push a new version to PlayStore or iTuneStore, but users has to manually update the application.  Is there any way to update the resources(such as JavaScript, JSON or CSS) in assets folder? I gave a try, but failed. Assume that as part of a WebService request or push notification, I will get a list of files that are modified on the web server. How can I get these files in my hybrid app?

Please help if any of you faced the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check out the `FileSystem` and the `FileTransfer` APIs

Answer (score 0):

I still did not get a concrete answer . But there is a tool called TriggerIO which offers this feature. Also PhoneGap cloud provides this for collaborative testing.
I believe behind the scene they may be using ApplicationCache to check for the resources.

Depends on your app usecase there is another way too. If you are okay for lesser performance, rather than packaging your static files along with the bundle, refer it from web. In config.xml, content src="mydomain.com/index.html". I use this for a specific product implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can remote update your hybrid apps with *codova-app-loader*, please refer https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-app-loader.